# SSL certificate expiration date on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, http, ssl-certificate

Can anybody provide me a C++ implementation rather simple to get SSL certificate expiration date. I have been looking online for past many hours, couldn't find anything so far. Currently I am using libcpr, and it doesn't seem to have any way to get it. I tried using the "curl" command, but that also doesn't seem to have that particular information in the output on **Windows** OS. The same command give the "expire date" in the output if I run it in GitBash, but not in the windows command prompt. I am new to C++.

The command below and output is from GitBash.

```
$ curl --insecure -vvI https://www.example.com
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Los Angeles; 
   O=Internet▒Corporation▒for▒Assigned▒Names▒and▒Numbers; CN=www.example.org
*  start date: Mar 14 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 14 23:59:59 2023 GMT    <-------- **********
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), 
   continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* h2h3 [:method: HEAD]
* h2h3 [:path: /]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: www.example.com]
* h2h3 [user-agent: curl/7.83.0]
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x16d9a46c1d0)
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
```

Any help would be appriciated!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to refer to the code in this [issue](https://gist.github.com/cseelye/adcd900768ff61f697e603fd41c67625):

```
ASN1_TIME *expires = X509_get_notAfter(cert.get());

// Construct another ASN1_TIME for the unix epoch, get the difference
// between them and use that to calculate a unix timestamp representing
// when the cert expires
ASN1_TIME_ptr epoch(ASN1_TIME_new(), ASN1_STRING_free);
ASN1_TIME_set_string(epoch.get(), "700101000000");
int days, seconds;
ASN1_TIME_diff(&days, &seconds, epoch.get(), expires);
time_t expire_timestamp = (days * 24 * 60 * 60) + seconds;

std::cout << "Expiration timestamp:" << std::endl;
std::cout << expire_timestamp << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
```